# text-overflow: ellipsis not working with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I created a table which consists out of div elements which all use `display: flex`. I also use `display: flex` on the cell element because I'm using other flex properties to center the text.

My problem is that the text in a cell of the table doesn't get shortened even tho it has `text-overflow: ellipsis` set in the css and is overflowing.

Removing `display: flex` from the cell element makes the text wrap and actually use `text-overflow: ellipsis` but I really want this to work with flexbox and I'm sure there is a solution for this.

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-inline: 5px;
}

.cell:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">Column 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Column 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">Text that is really long</div>
    <div class="cell">Text that is even longer than the really long one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">Text that is really long</div>
    <div class="cell">Text that is even longer than the really long one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">Text that is really long</div>
    <div class="cell">Text that is even longer than the really long one</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-overflow` property only works on block containers. You can wrap the text in a separate element inside the cell and apply `text-overflow: ellipsis` to that element instead.

```
...
.text-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
...
<div class="cell">
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    Text that is even longer than the really long one
  </div>
</div>
```